# Can't call Datepicker in my Laravel application

Tags: php, jquery

When I try to use jQuery in my Laravel framework I can't seem to call date picker. What did I miss?

[image: Mycode]

Comment: Please include your code directly in the question. The image is hard to read

Comment: Follow this link  : https://hdtuto.com/article/how-to-use-bootstrap-datepicker-in-laravel-5-

Answer (score 1):

It would be best if you use jQuery UI for the Datepicker.

```
npm i jquery-ui
```

Or you can use just the Datepicker.

```
npm i jquery-datepicker
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-datepicker